# Play a binary string with the HTML audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, audio

I have a server that serves ogg encoded audio to a client that requests it with a http GET. 
If I inject the GET route into the HTML audio src it receives the audio and plays it:

```Javascript
function working(text) {
    var downloadURL = 'http://localhost:8080/nlc/synthesize' +
        '?text=' + encodeURIComponent(text);

    audio.pause();
    audio.src = downloadURL;
    audio.play();

};
```

If I use a http GET call (in AngularJS) and try to inject the response into the HTML audio src it won't play it:

```Javascript
function not_working(text) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/nlc/synthesize' + '?text=' + encodeURIComponent(text)).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      audio.pause();
      audio.src = encodeURIComponent(response);
      audio.play();

};
```

The log of the response shows a JSON with a binary string at the 'data' key:

```
Object {data: "OggS�1�/ڂ OpusHead��]OggS…�xs���������������������������������", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

Is there a way to decode the http GET response into something I can inject into the audio src?

Comment: I dont know about angular, but with XMLHttpRequest, your can set its `.responseType` to `"blob"`, and then create an `objectURL`from this blob response (`URL.createObjectURL(this.response)`) that you will be able to pass as the `src` of your audio element. Otherwise, if your targeted browsers do support the AudioContextAPI, you can use the [`AudioContext.decodeAudioData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/decodeAudioData) method.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to do it with this code:

```Javascript
function working(text) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/nlc/synthesize';
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        responseType: 'blob',
        data: {
            "text": text
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }

    $http(req).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        audio.pause();
        audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        audio.play();
    })
};
```

Comment: Where are you getting the audio variable from in the response handling code?

Answer (score 0):

in http.get you can pass a dict with optional config

```
$http.get(Url, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
})
.success(function(){
})
.error(function(){
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

maybe you can combine this with the comment of @kaiido